# Spreadsheet: How can I merge every nth line with a previous line?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet where **each cell contains multiple key value pairs.** **Every value is on a new line.** The content of every cell is the following: [cell content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuIJf.png) I need to somehow merge the every second line in the cell with the previous line, so that **every key value pair would be in a single line:** [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rL8l.png)
How can I do that? I tried to match new line character `\n` with a regex and replace it with a space, but it merges every line in a cell into one line: [replaced \n characters with space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLc4w.png)
[Example Google Sheet file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1USmjmBYLHMhdagKZcg95vr3dK-ARmV4evbBsLma2ICI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser plz [edit] your post & share formula or method U have applied so far,, ! Write us what OUTPUT you are expecting as IMAGE 1 or 2 or 3 even.

Comment: Is it better now? @RajeshS

Comment: I think all are in one cell separated by Line break ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer on [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/251055/calc-how-can-i-merge-every-nth-line-with-a-previous-line/)

Find: **([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)**

Replace: **$1 $2**
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRA6h.png) solved it.